# Symfony Trailing Slash Redirection Drops HTTPS

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, https, trailing-slash

I have a Symfony endpoint that looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/")
 */
public function testAction(){
    return new JsonResponse(['hello' => 'world']);
}
```

When I serve it on my HTTPS-enabled server (or ngrok), the following works:

```
curl https://subdomain.ngrok.io/controller/test/
```

It outputs:

> {"hello":"world"}

However, when I try the following (note the missing trailing slash):

```
curl https://subdomain.ngrok.io/controller/test
```

I receive a redirection website, and the following response header:

> Location: http://subdomain.ngrok.io/controller/test/

It adds the trailing slash, but seems to change the protocol to HTTP. That would be easily resolved by replacing `@Route("/test/")` with `@Route("/test")`, in which case the match would work for both missing and present trailing slashes. However, I'd rather make sure that for whenever Symfony decides that a redirection is necessary, it maintains the protocol.

There are tutorials about how to enforce HTTPS everywhere, but that's not what I'm interested in. What I need is for Symfony to never *change* the protocol when it creates redirections. How do I do that?

EDIT: What's worse is that those are 301 redirects. Which means if it's ever accessed from a browser, the damage is fairly permanent.

EDIT 2: When removing the trailing slash from the `@Route` parameter, it stops redirecting to URLs that include a trailing slash, so `.../test` will work. However, even though `.../test/` won't redirect to `.../test`, it will now throw a 404. So Symfony automatically appends slashes to URLs for redirection, but it doesn't subtract them.

Comment: To my knowledge symfony doesn't automatically remove/add slashes, what do you use for adding/removing slashes? webserver, kernel listener?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It's doing it pretty much of its own accord. I don't recall adding nor do I see any additional settings in any of the config files.

Comment: some web-server rewrite rule?

Comment: No, it happens both with Ngrok and my own webserver. I'm about 98% confident that Ngrok doesn't have any special rewrite rules, especially because when removing the trailing slash in the annotation, it works without a redirection.

Comment: Please see my second edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is related to the `trustedProxies` value on the `Request` object. Symfony doesn't listen to the HTTP proxy forwarding headers (specifically `X-Forwarded-Proto`) unless the proxy is listed in the trusted proxies.

Adding this to your Symfony `index.php` or `app.php`, should solve the issue for ngrok.

```
if ($debug) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(
        [$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']],
        Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO
    );
}
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html for more information on the options.